# How to debug Google Cloud Dataflow Streaming Engine outage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-stackdriver

We are running some stream processing in Google Cloud Dataflow using the Streaming Engine option. This morning some data was missing, so I tried to do some troubleshooting. The only thing I found, seems to be a restart of the worker (see the screenshot of the log file). None of the logs show any errors or exceptions.

[image: Dataflow log]

We are quite new to GCP, so we do not know our way around so well. Is there any way to find the root cause for the worker restart? Or is this is just an infrastructure error?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the upstream datasource where your DataFlow pipline is writing to? If your sync is not able to keep up with your DataFlow job then please take a look at this article which seems to suggest a solution:
https://medium.com/google-cloud/restarting-cloud-dataflow-in-flight-9c688c49adfd

Behaviour you mentioned seem to match with the following two scenarios :

> **Slow-running pipelines or lack of output.** If your pipeline runs slowly or runs for a long period of time without reporting results, you might check your quotas for streaming data sources and sinks such as Pub/Sub. There are also certain transforms that are better-suited to high-volume streaming pipelines than others.
>
> **Errors caused by transient failures in other Google Cloud services.** Your pipeline may fail because of a temporary outage or other problem in the Google Cloud services upon which Dataflow depends, such as Compute Engine or Cloud Storage, which you can monitor from: https://status.cloud.google.com/. Status board reports a recent issue with compute engine, does that correlate with your outage?

[image]

For more steps about troubleshooting dataflow pipeline see: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshooting-your-pipeline

Hope this helps.

Comment: - Upstream datasource is a Cloud SQL. I experienced issues here, but then we have exceptions and Dataflow will retry, not show today's behaviour.
- The article is about updating a running pipeline.I have tried that many times and this works good. Today's behaviour was a pipeline restarting itself.
- The source is Pub/Sub, here the unacked message count rose, which fits with Dataflow not reading messages any longer (until the restart). There are no 429 quota errors (or anything else)
- There are no outages on the GCP status board, but I guess not everything is on there..
- No exceptions

Comment: Does GCP compute outage coincide with your timing? I would assume under the hood dataflow workers are compute instances

Comment: The outages on the dashboard were a couple of days okay. Mine was this morning

Comment: In that case, it might be worth contacting Google Cloud Support, explain the above issue or point them to this thread and see what they say.